# "No mapper registered for java.util.Optional" using JDBI v2 and java.util.Optional

Tags: java, jdbi

When I try code like this:

```java
...
import java.util.Optional;
import org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.Bind;
import org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.SqlQuery;
import org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.customizers.RegisterMapper;
...

public abstract class SomethingDAO {
    @RegisterMapper(SomethingMapper.class)
    @SqlQuery("sql/something_select_by_id.sql")
    abstract Optional<Something> selectById(@Bind("id") long id);
}
```

Why does it generate an error like this?

```
org.skife.jdbi.v2.MappingRegistry$1: No mapper registered for java.util.Optional

    at org.skife.jdbi.v2.MappingRegistry.mapperFor(MappingRegistry.java:83)
    at org.skife.jdbi.v2.RegisteredMapper.map(RegisteredMapper.java:35)
    at org.skife.jdbi.v2.Query$4.munge(Query.java:183)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the annotation `@SingleValueResult`, like this:

```java
public abstract class SomethingDAO {
    @RegisterMapper(SomethingMapper.class)
    @SqlQuery("sql/something_select_by_id.sql")
    @SingleValueResult
    abstract Optional<Something> selectById(@Bind("id") long id);
}
```

Comment: After JDBI3 this does not longer work. That is, even if I replace SingleValueResult with the V3 replacement SingleValue I get the "No mapper registered.."

Comment: Has anyone figured out how to do this in JDBI v3?

Answer (score 0):

With "pure" JDBI (v2) you need to configure DBI instance with ContainerFactory.
[Here's the ContainerFactory for Optionals in dropwizard-jdbi](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/v1.3.1/dropwizard-jdbi/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/jdbi/OptionalContainerFactory.java)
Then you should add it upon DBI instance creation:

```
 dbi.registerContainerFactory(new OptionalContainerFactory());
```